# std::map<struct, int> Do I need destructor ?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

Hi in a cpp class X I have a

```
class X{
    private:
        std::map<some_struct, int> C;
}
```

Where some_struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}some_struct;
```

My question is: do I need to specify anything about the map C in X's destructor?
If yes, what action should X's destructor do for map C?

Comment: Make a remove function or erase function that goes through every element and erase/removes it from the map and call that function in you destructor in class X.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI please don't do that. destructor of  `std::map` does it at a more efficient manner

Comment: you should just follow rule of zero: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to specify a destructor for `some_struct` or `class X`

For any types it is generated by the compiler automatically. As long there wasn't anything explicitly allocated with the class at dynamic storage with `new` or `new []`, you don't need to write a destructor that applies a `delete`  or `delete[]` operation.

---

Also for writing c++ code (vs c) you don't need to use that `typedef` syntax:

```
struct some_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Comment: The destructor is generated for all types

Comment: All classes have destructor generated automatically

Comment: "As long there wasn't anything explicitly allocated with the class..."  The class being referred to is X.  If some_struct allocates memory, that should be freed in sone_struct's destructor.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't introduce `new` operators, you're good to go with the default destructor.

**ALL** STL containers (map, vector, list, deque, etc...) don't need special destructors. They are self-contained and cleanly designed to destroy themselves once you go out of scope.

Comment: `new` operator is not a good indicator that you need destructor or not. I can have `unique_ptr<some_struct>(new some_struct)` and still save

Comment: @BryanChen still the statement "if there is no new you are fine with the default destructor" holds. It does not imply the reverse: if you have new, then you need more than the default destrcutor, as your counter example demonstrates

Comment: @BryanChen you could do that but it is a bug.  If the smart pointer constructor throws then you have leaked the memory.  That is one of the reasons the make functions should be used

Comment: @NathanOliver that's just another reason to avoid `new`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to worry about `C` in destructor if you had dynamically allocated object on heap with `new` operator, for example:

```
class X{
    public:
        X();
    private:
        std::map<some_struct, int> *p_C;
}
```

And in definition:

```
X::X() {
  p_C = new map<some_struct, int>();
}

X::~X() {
  if(p_C) delete p_C;
}
```

Comment: no you don't because you'd be using smart pointers in that case

Comment: What's a _heap_ by means of the c++ standards?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ who's nitpicking now :P

Comment: @M.M That's a serious nitpick at least :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not really, it's commonly understood that *heap* refers to dynamic allocation

Comment: @M.M _" it's commonly understood ..."_ The standard specification has no notion about that though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nobody cares except you; this isn't a language-lawyer question nor answer and everybody can figure out what is meant

Comment: @M.M Me might be heavy enough :P You can always counter upvote. Advising `new` and `delete` is going down the wrong direction though. If that would be appropriate halfway, there should be a mention of smart pointers.